# Backbone click event being fired multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js, parse-platform

I have seen many questions about this, but no one is solving my problem.

I have a page with a main `div` which has one `div` `one-image` by default. There is also a button so you can add other `div`s. So I have an event `click` which appends this other `div` template with a "remove" button. Like this:

#### Image stack

```
<div class="image-stack">
  <div class="one-image">
     ...
     <a id="addImage">Add another image</a>
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Image template

```
<script type="text/template" id="another-image-template">
  <div class="one-image">
     ...
     <a id="addImage">Add another image</a>
     <a id="removeImage">Remove image</a>
     ...
  </div>
</script>
```

#### View

```
events: { 
          'click #addImage' : 'addAnotherImage',
          'click #removeImage' : 'removeThisImage'
},

addAnotherImage: function(e) {
  var another = $('#another-image-template').html();
  $('.images-stack').append(another);
},

removeThisImage: function(e) {
  $(e.currentTarget).closest('.one-image').remove();
}
```

This works fine. When I click the "Add" button, it adds a new `one-image` `div` under the last one; and when I click the "Remove" button, it removes the `div` I clicked. If I change the view and come back to the same view (always created with `new` in Backbone), the `image-stack` has one `div` `one-image` only, which is fine. But when I click the "Add" button, it appends **two** `one-image` `div`s. And if I repeat the previous steps, it appends *three*.

I have checked and the function is being called twice (and thrice and so...). I don't understand why this is happening since `remove()` is removing the object from the DOM and I always initialize the `view` with `new`. Any ideas?

Comment: IDs must be unique, you are generating invalid markup. Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Oh man! Totally my bad! But bad news are that I still have the same issue. And even worst, it works fine on http://jsfiddle.net/oy1t38ho/

Comment: Could it be something related to the way I use Backbone? Maybe it *saves* somehow the DOM?

Comment: When the handlers are called several times there are 2 possible reasons: Either you, after appending elements, have several nested elements  that all of them match with the handler selector, as the `click` event _propagates_ the handler is called once for each element. Or the elements have several direct event handlers attached to them, this happens when one binds handler in the context of another handler.

Comment: Sounds good! I'll take a look at that and come back to you ;)

Comment: Technically, <a> tags without href properties are also invalid....not that that's your problem....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is probably related to not closing and unbinding your views. It is called zombie views. By calling `this.remove()` and `this.off()` should cleanup all references to the view.

Have a look at the following:

- `this.remove()` - http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove
- `this.off()` - http://backbonejs.org/#Events-off

and

- https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/
- [Backbone zombie views & good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916009/backbone-zombie-views-good-practice)
- [Preventing backbone zombie views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495855/preventing-backbone-zombie-views)

Comment: It was a bit hard for me to solve this, because my Backbone app was not using Backbone "workflow" correctly. But this showed me the way!